# How to set the default file(starting point) in dot net core

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I am trying to explore the dot net core functionality to get better understanding on it, for the same i executed

```
dotnet new
dotnet build
dotnet run
```

command in command prompt window, it created a project for me and file with name `Project.cs` has been created and at last it showed `Hello World!` in the window.

Now i added one more file in the same folder structure with different name `SampleDotNetCoreApp.cs`, i want to know how i can set `SampleDotNetCoreApp.cs` as the default starting point of the program execution when i will execute `dotnet run` command.

In other words i want to know how i can change the starting execution point in dot net core when i have multiple cs file in the same folder.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can edit the "Project.csproj" file to specify which `Main` method is used

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <StartupObject>Project.SampleDotNetCoreApp</StartupObject>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Note the `StartupObject` tag, identifying the class to start the program with. This class must have a `static Main(string[] args)` method.

Use `dotnet restore` to ensure the changes are saved successfully, then build / run the project

> `dotnet run` and `dotnet build` do perform an automatic restore, so doing this manually is not necessary

- Yes, I know I'm late to the party, but I just encountered this issue and found it hard to solve. Might as well share my newfound wisdom.

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to address this - without removing code making sure that you only have one main method, and at least given:

`.NET Command Line Tools (1.1.6)`

with 
`Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.3.409.57025 for .NET Core`

is to invoke the build with the following arguments:

`dotnet build /property:StartupObject=namespace.ClassWithMain`

It is very confusing that the error message points you to a `/main` which is not supported at all - I eventually found out the right property to use (note, I had used /property:main or /property:Main to no avail) from this answer here: [dotnet build specify main method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43365254/dotnet-build-specify-main-method?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Hope it helps

Comment: `/main` or `-main` is an option for the C# compiler executable, `csc.exe`. It should be equivalent to the MSBuild property `StartupObject`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/advanced

Answer (score 1):

The entry point of the program is defined by a static `Main` method.

When executing `dotnet new`, this creates `Program.cs` with this method inside:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
}
```

And this becomes the entry-point of the program (as it is the only `static Main` method in the project.

To add a new `.cs` file with a `static Main` method from the command-line, you can use:

```
echo using System;namespace ConsoleApplication{public class SampleDotNetCoreApp{public static void Main(string[] args){Console.WriteLine("Hello NEW World!");}}} > SampleDotNetCoreApp.cs
```

However, if you now run `dotnet build` you will get this error:

> Program has more than one entry point defined. Compile with /main to specify the type that contains the entry point.

Because there are 2 `static Main` methods. I have not been able to work out what it means by `Compile with /main`, but to overcome this error you can run a similar `echo` command as above, but this time altering `Program.cs`:

```
echo using System;namespace ConsoleApplication{public class Program{public static void MainOLD(string[] args){Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");}}} > Program.cs
```

Now that you only have 1 `static Main`, you can run

```
dotnet build
dotnet run
```

And see the output:

```
Hello NEW World!
```

This is almost certainly not the recommended way of doing this, but hopefully it can give you some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
"entryPoint": "ADifferentMethod"
```

in top level of project.json.

Please refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/project-json#entrypoint for more details.

Comment: like java uses javac -"filename", do we have something in dot net core relevant to the same such that i can execute different files

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to specify an entry point via CLI using the `StartupProject` property.

```
dotnet build --p StartupObject=yournamespace.ClassWithMain
dotnet run --p StartupObject=yournamespace.ClassWithMain
```