# 'dotnet build' specify main method

Tags: c#, msbuild, .net-core

I am using `dotnet` to build a .NET Core C# project from the command line. The project has multiple classes with a `main` method. Thus I get the error:

```
$ dotnet build
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.1.548.43366
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Test.cs(18,28): error CS0017: Program has more than one entry point defined. Compile with /main to specify the type that contains the entry point.

Build FAILED.
```

Passing the `/main` switch results in the error:

```
$ dotnet build /main:Test
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.1.548.43366
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

MSBUILD : error MSB1001: Unknown switch.
Switch: /main:Test
```

How can I pass the `/main` switch to the `dotnet` command?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can edit your csproj to define which class to use (inside a `PropertyGroup`):

```
<StartupObject>foo.Program2</StartupObject>
```

or specify this MSBuild property on the command line via:

```
$ dotnet build foo.csproj -p:StartupObject=foo.Program2
```

where

```
namespace foo
{
  class Program2{ public static void Main() {} }
}
```

Comment: I spent the past hour trying a few things until I found your answer. Thank you so much for taking the time to document this!

Comment: Late to the game here, but does make sense in a Web Application? In VS 2017 the startup object is set to Project. Don't think that's a valid value for the tag.

Also, unfortunately, I don't have a Test project (existing code base), so the answers relating to an entry point for the application, and an entry point for the test project doesn't apply.

Please advise.

Comment: @EoRaptor013 this question is about multiple classes with at public static `Main()` method where the compiler needs to decide between one of them. That has nothing to do with sln files that contain multiple projects.

Comment: What is `foo` and what is `Program2`? Is it namespace and file name?

Comment: @Morasiu it wants the full name of the class (i.e. `Namespace.ClassName`) containing a `Main` method: here `foo` would be the NameSpace, `Program2` would be the name of the class (which need not be in a file called `Program2.cs`)

Answer (score 3):

Just to add why calling `dotnet` with `/main` fails with that error, note that it says "**Compile** with `/main`"; `/main` is a [parameter for the compiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/) (`csc.exe`), not [`dotnet build`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build).  `dotnet build` will invoke [`MSBuild.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference) which, in turn, will invoke `csc.exe`, but you'll need to tell `dotnet build` what the startup class is so it can tell `csc.exe`.  This is what the accepted answer does.

Alternatively, if you were calling `csc.exe` directly, you could pass `/main` to it like so...

```
csc.exe Program.cs Test.cs /main:TestNamespace.Test
```