# Porting a solution with multiple startup projects from .NET Framework 4.7.1 to .NET Core 2.1

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-webapi, porting

I'm in the process of migrating my solution from .NET Standard (targeting .NET Framework 4.7.1) to .NET Core (targeting *netcoreapp2.1*). My solution consists of 12 projects, two of which are web API projects that both need to run simultaneously.

I changed the targets in all my solution's .csproj from "net471" to "netcoreapp2.1". In a few cases I also had to update the APIs in code. There are still several warnings I'm dealing with regarding potential package incompatibility.

However my main problem is the following error:

> Error    CS0017    Program has more than one entry point defined. Compile with /main to specify the type that contains the entry point.    Foo.Api    D:\Code\Product\Foo\src\Foo.Api\Program.cs    9    Active

My solution has two startup projects, as it consists of two APIs that are related but separate. I don't want to specify one as the main as I need them both to start up when starting my solution, and under .NET Framework this was no problem.

Is it possible to have these projects start up together?

Note that if I add `<StartupObject>Foo.Api.Program</StartupObject>` to one of my API projects [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43365254/dotnet-build-specify-main-method), I can successfully get that project to start. I think this is equivalent to compiling with /main. I cannot, however, get the other API project to start the same way. Instead, I can `dotnet run` that project and have them both running. However, the compile time error needs to be resolved for it to get through our release pipeline.

There are definitely only these two Main methods in my solution. Here is the results of a find on `void Main`:

[image]

Comment: this may help: https://andrewlock.net/fixing-the-error-program-has-more-than-one-entry-point-defined-for-console-apps-containing-xunit-tests/

Comment: Thanks @JohnB but I believe that link deals with this error being generated unit test project main method conflicting with the production project main method. In this case, you can suppress the generation of the test project main method. In my case I want and need both projects to have a main method that starts up. My solution cannot involve suppressing one of my projects.

Comment: A C# program (not solution) can only have one Program.Main(). Main is the first method run when the program starts, so the compiler needs to know which one is the real one, and it can't if you have two.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @DalmTo, but both my startup projects (not solution) have exactly one `Program.Main()` so they should both be able to run.

Comment: @Ivan the error message you are getting contradicts that.  I suggest that you check again.

Comment: You're correct, the error message seems inaccurate, hence why I turned to SO for help. Bear in mind that this solution was running fine under .NET Framework 4.7.1. It's only under .NET Core that I have encountered this problem.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this error, Referring to this [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/2796) suggests that it may be an unknown environment problem. Try building on another PC / clean profile / clean install.

Comment: Your question is not clear. An ASP.NET Core project can target either .NET Core or .NET Framework. If your APIs are ASP.NET Core projects, there should be no difference code-wise switching the target from .NET Framework to .NET Core unless you're using Windows-specific APIs not supported by .NET Core. It's possible you're *also* attempting to upgrade ASP.NET Core at the same time, but you've haven't stated anything to that effect. The other alternative is that your APIs are actually ASP.NET Web Apis, in which case, you must do a complete rewrite.

Comment: Could not reproduce your issue with one solution which contains two web api project? Is there any demo to reproduce your issue?

Comment: @ChrisPratt Please could you phrase your comment as a question, so I can clarify? I'm retargeting all 12 ASP.NET Core projects in my solution from .NET Framework ("net471") to .NET Core ("netcoreapp2.1"). There were slight code changes for packages that I'd upgraded to support the change.

Comment: @AdamVincent and TaoZhou I'm not able to share the entire codebase nor have I seen this issue with any other project, but I will try to reproduce it in a demo repo and get back to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is resolved, but I am still not sure what caused it.

I was referencing a few packages that gave the following warning:

> Warning  NU1701  Package 'CacheManager.SystemRuntimeCaching 1.1.2' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.

I upgraded most of them, with the exception above, and I was able to run and debug both startup projects simultaneously without error. My guess is there was some kind of conflict with one of these packages.