# StartupObject has different behavior when running from command line than when modifying CSPROJ file

Tags: c#, .net-core, command-line-interface

I just stumbled across the `StartupObject` parameter for MSBuild, which allows for explicit specification of a projects entry point. Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43365254/dotnet-build-specify-main-method) it looks like there are two ways to specify this parameters:

- In the CSPROJ file for the given project
- Specifying as an MSBuild property using `dotnet` CLI.

I'm interested in the second option, so I made a simple console application with two files, `First.cs` and `Second.cs`:

### `First.cs`

```
using System;

internal class First
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("First");
    }
}
```

### `Second`

```
using System;

internal class Second
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Second");
    }
}
```

What I found out is that specifying `StartupObject` via the `dotnet` CLI will call the correct startup object *only* if running from a clean slate:

```
PS> dotnet run --project=test_multiple_entry -p:StartupObject=First
First
PS> dotnet run --project=test_multiple_entry -p:StartupObject=Second
First
PS> dotnet clean test_multiple_entry
...
PS> dotnet run --project=test_multiple_entry -p:StartupObject=Second
Second
```

On the other hand, if I actually modify the entry point from the CSPROJ file, no `dotnet clean` is necessary, and it will automatically go find the correct entry point.

I'm curious as to whether this behavior is intentional? Why does `dotnet run` not use the correct entry point unless preceded by a `dotnet clean`? Why does modifying the CSPROJ file directly simply work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

StartupObject is a build property, not a runtime property. When `dotnet` run sees that a build is required (such as a source file (including the csproj) is newer than the build output, or there's no build output (after `dotnet clean`)) then it cascades to `dotnet build` first, and passes through all the -p arguments to the build.

Comment: So the only way to get it to reflect the StartupObject parameter specified through the command line is to first `clean` and then `run`? Is there another command or way that I could get it to work in one go?

Comment: If you want runtime behavior you would be better served by having just one Main method and doing argument parsing. StartupObject’s purpose is essentially for when you’ve combined multiple projects together (or have shared source code) and need to tell the build which Main is the “real” one

Comment: I do a lot of one-off "scripts" to demonstrate very minimal functionality to myself in C# because I am a novice. So far I have been making a whole new project for every little "script". This is a bit of an overkill since it results in a lot of garbage data which I don't need. Specifying multiple main entry points in a single project might be a good intermediate solution for me, albeit requiring a `clean` and `run` each time I want to "select" another "script"