# Setting compile include in C# project from command line

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

I have a .NET project containing two source files `A.cs` and `B.cs`:

### `A.cs`

```
using System;


public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("running program A");
    }
}
```

### `B.cs`

```
using System;


public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("running program B");
    }
}
```

The CSPROJ file contains the following:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="A.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>


  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>namespace_test</RootNamespace>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <EnableDefaultCompileItems>false</EnableDefaultCompileItems>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

I've found that if I change the file in the item group to `<Compile Include="B.cs" />` and rerun the program using `dotnet run`, `msbuild` will ignore `A.cs` and rebuild the application with `A.cs`.

I would like to see whether I can control this from the command line using either `msbuild` or `dotnet`. Is there a command line switch that would help me do that without having to open the CSPROJ file every time?

Comment: Why don't you use a solution, have two different projects for those and then run the solution with the respective startupproject set? - Or on the cmd-line, you'll start the respective project.

Comment: @Fildor yes, that is true, but there are some [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72603693/startupobject-has-different-behavior-when-running-from-command-line-than-when-mo). Also, creating a new project has more overhead than just selecting which files to include in the compilation.

Comment: _"Also, creating a new project has more overhead than just selecting which files to include in the compilation."_ - Well, considering you are supposed to have only one single Class containing a Main in one project, I'd at least consider that to be arguable. I mean: how much time have you already spent on this? Just creating two separate projects in a solution would have already been faster, I bet.

Comment: The "problems" do not apply to my suggested solution, btw. In the linked question, the author uses _one_ project and tries to use different startup-objects while I suggested using _two different_ projects.

Comment: @Fildor I really would like to see if there's a way to circumvent having multiple projects, *and* have multiple files with a `Main` method. I realize this might be counterintuitive to someone who already has .NET experience, and indeed probably bad practice, but this is for purely educational purposes.

Comment: *I suggested using two different projects.* Right, but I think your idea (if I understand it correctly) was to shift the problem up to the solution level and use `StartupProject` instead of `StartupObject`... which would mean I'd have to have multiple projects, which I'm trying to avoid...

Comment: StartupProject is relevant in Visual Studio. You can have different profiles for that. Using `dotnet run` on the cmd-line, you target projects, anyway.

Comment: The command line tools won't support what you intend to do, because it is explicitly not supposed to work that way. So if you absolutely want to push through, you'll need to work some magic, I guess. Maybe by having two csproj-Files and having a script copying the selected one or renaming them ... but honestly: I'd consider that extremely hacky.